CLI or Hotkey friendly web browser?
I guess I've become one of those people that doesn't want to take their hands away from the keyboard when using a computer... I can of course keep on using mouse and keyboard, but I figure it wouldn't hurt to ask about what exists in the current state.
One of my pain points for trying to go keyboard-only is web browsers. Sometimes I feel like it would be faster to download the raw HTML and use Vim motions to navigate for all the time I feel would be wasted hitting [TAB] + [TAB] + ... in the browser. I'm only half kidding.
While PG UP, PG DN, [SPACE] + [SHIFT] + [SPACE] are definitely nice for purely reading, it does not help me when I want to efficiently select and interact with the site.
I'm still looking into what is possible with hotkeys, however I was curious if anyone has made a web browser which is specialized to navigate and interact with sites via keyboard only. Or even a plugin? Anything like that exist?
